# How should I use cx_freeze with a Macports library?

Tags: python, macos, macports, cx-freeze

I'm currently using the Python 3.4 Mac OS X build from Python.org. I'm using a Python module that depends on a library that I built in Macports. The script does not run out-of-the-box:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "magnetx.py", line 6, in <module>
    import yara
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/yara.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libyara.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/yara.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I can fix this if I set an environment variable

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/local/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Unfortunately, it does not satisfy cx_freeze. It keeps looking in `/usr/local/lib`, when it should be looking in `/opt/local/lib`.

> copying
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/yara.so
>   -> build/exe.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/yara.so copying /usr/local/lib/libyara.3.dylib ->
>   build/exe.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/libyara.3.dylib error: [Errno 2] No
>   such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libyara.3.dylib'

I could probably build Python in Macports, but that seems like it should be unnecessary. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: How did you obtain `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/yara.so`? Does it come with your version of Python or did you install it later on?

Comment: I installed yara-python after building libyara in mac ports. Just tried using mac port's python. now I get `
dyld: Library not loaded:
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Python :\`

Answer (score 2):

On OS X, dependent libraries are referenced using absolute paths. The path that gets copied into your binary depends on the so-called "install name" of the library you link against at build time. In your case, the `yara.so` does not reference the library you would like it to load. Let's explore a couple of reasons why this could be the case, and a couple of ways to fix that:

- I've verified that `libyara.dylib` as installed by MacPorts (on my system) has an install name of `/opt/local/lib/libyara.0.dylib`. Sometimes, build systems that don't use a cross-platform library build tool and don't expect the peculiarities of OS X mess this up (and use relative paths or `/usr/local/lib`). If this was the case, it would be a bug in the software's build system, which could be manually fixed using `install_name_tool(1)`'s `-id` flag (before linking against the library).
- Your copy of `yara.so` may have been built against a different version of `libyara.dylib` that resides in `/usr/local/lib`. That would explain why your `yara.so` does not contain the correct absolute path to the MacPorts copy of `libyara.dylib`, but it would also prevent the error you're seeing from happening in the first place, unless you had a copy in `/usr/local/lib` at build time and deleted it later on. As you've already seen, you can instruct OS X' loader to also search different paths using the `DYLD_*` series of environment variables. My take on why this doesn't work for `cx_freeze` is that it doesn't pay attention to the `DYLD_*` series of variables.
- If you are sure that the copy of `libyara.dylib` `yara.so` expects to find in `/usr/local/lib` is binary-compatible with the one in `/opt/local/lib`, you can manually modify the library load commands in `yara.so` to point to the latter path using `install_name_tool(1)`'s `-change old new` parameter, e.g. `install_name_tool -change /usr/local/lib/libyara.3.dylib /opt/local/lib/libyara.0.dylib /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/yara.so`. This is essentially modifying the binary with the change the loader did for you when you set `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`. Since the library major version numbers seem to be different, this may not be a safe assumption.
- If you don't know whether `yara.so` is compatible with MacPorts' build of `libyara.0.dylib`, you can and should recompile `yara.so`. If the re-compile went right, you should be able to check the library load commands using `otool -L yara.so` and see the paths beginning with `/opt/local` in there (provided that `otool -D /opt/local/lib/libyara.0.dylib` correctly points to itself).

Edit: I've just re-checked and noticed that my MacPorts build's library version number differs from the one your system expects. That sounds a lot like case number 2 to me.

Comment: I built libyara and yara-python myself, the versions match. After I installed python34 on macports and used that, I now get dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Python

Comment: Do you have any `DYLD_*` variabes set? Does `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Python` exist?

Comment: No and yes. This question really doesn't apply anymore; I'm having different problems. [See my new question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777340/cx-freeze-linking-to-libraries-in-opt-local-rather-than-the-ones-it-copied-over)